# Does phpMyAdmin SQL command differ from sqlbuddy?

Tags: phpmyadmin, sqlbuddy

I'm learning php/mysql, I have made a php page and I have a form on a host that has a sqlbuddy database, when I ws a adding a column in the table but the I got this:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''fan_comments' ADD 'dates' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' at line 1

This is what is my statement:
ALTER TABLE 'fan_comments' ADD 'dates' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

But running the same command on my machine which uses phpMyAdmin the command works perfectly so I'm confused what the problem is..what can I do to correct that error?

Comment: I don't think that this has to do with either phpMyAdmin or sqlbuddy. Probably the MySQL server version on both machines is different. Try to change the single quotes (`'`) to reversed ones (`\``).

Comment: Ohh didn't know those single reverse quotes had any significance or made any difference I just tried them and it works correctly and also works without any quotes around table name and column...thnx lex :)

Comment: No problem. I recommend using the reversed quotes, because you will need them if one of your column names happens to be an SQL keyword. So that's something to keep in mind.